# C array reverse, can't find the bug

Tags: c

The following code is supposed to reverse an array but it is not working.
I can't find the bug (sorry but I am an amateur).

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int ara[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
    int i, j, temp;

    for (i=0, j=9; i<10; i++, j--) {
        temp = ara[j];
        ara[j] = ara[i];
        ara[i] = temp;
    }
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", ara[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You reverse it twice: http://ideone.com/zniRSa

Comment: `i` should go only upto midpoint, otherwise the swapping will occur twice and array is unchanged

Comment: How many times each element is swapped?

Comment: Perhaps `i < j` ??

Comment: Thanks everyone, I get it now. You guys are genius!

Comment: Instead of *hardcoding* `9 & 10`, use `int n = sizeof ara/sizeof *ara;` to get the number of elements in the array, then `j = n - 1`, etc.. (and no, we are not genius -- we've just done the same damn thing before `:)`

Comment: @pompom most of the exeprienced engineers on SO knew what the problem was before they opened your question:)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for (i=0, j=9; i<10; i++, j--) {
```

use

```
for (i=0, j=9; i<5; i++, j--) {           // Note 5 instead of 10
```

to stop iteration after *all `5` pairs* will be swapped.

Comment: How about `int n = sizeof ara/sizeof *ara;` and `for (i=0, j=n-1; i<j; i++, j--)`??